# starting a service in android from a broadcast receiver issue

Tags: android, service, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I know there are a bunch of these questions here on SO, but after scouring for possible solutions i failed to find one so any help here is appreciated.

I have 3 class files, my MainActivity with a checkbox that when pressed, starts an activity which has a broadcast Receiver, and my broadcast receiver is supposed to start a service to check for the users location.

The code is pretty big so i ll try showing only the main parts, if something else is needed please let me know.

In MainActivity:

```
     Public void onCheckboxClicked (View view) {
         boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
     Switch (view. getId ()) {
        case R.id.checkbox_gps:
            if (checked){
             Intent intent = new Intent(this, GPS_Info.class);
             startActivity(intent);
            }
```

In GPS_Info activity:

```
     public class GPS_Info extends Activity{
          private TextView latitude;
          private TextView longitude;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps_info);
     }

     private BroadcastReceiver GpsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
             System.out.println("Broadcast receiver");
             intent.setAction("com.example.systeminfo.GpsTracker");
             context.startService(intent);
        }
      };
```

My question i guess is, can i (and if yes then how) start the GpsTracker service which is in another class file within the broadcast receiver? What kind of intent do i need to sent? I havent fully grasped the idea of intents and contexts.

This is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.systeminfo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.systeminfo.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.systeminfo.GpsReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.systeminfo.LOCATION_READY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.systeminfo.GPS_Info"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_gps__info"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.systeminfo.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.systeminfo.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.systeminfo.BatteryStatus"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_battery_status"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.systeminfo.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.systeminfo.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.systeminfo.General_Info"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_general__info"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.systeminfo.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.systeminfo.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".GpsTracker"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false" >
        </service>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Also i know that broadcast receivers are not exactly needed for this senario i am describing, but its a requirement for the project.

Answer (score 0):

Right now based on your code the service will start when you broadcast 
com.example.systeminfo.LOCATION_READY intent... , when this intent will be broadcasted , in the onRecieve method service will start

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible)
So, you must to create ServiceConnection object (mConnection) and methods doBindService(), doUnbindService(). 
For example,

```
        /**
         * Class for interacting with the main interface of the service.
         */
        private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                    IBinder service) {
```

`mCallbackText.setText("Attached...");

            // We want to monitor the service for as long as we are
            // connected to it.
            try {

            } catch (RemoteException e) {  }

        }

        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            mCallbackText.setText("Disconnected...");
        }
    };

    // connect to service
    void doBindService() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyServer.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE | Context.BIND_IMPORTANT);

        mCallbackText.setText("Binding...");
    }

    void doUnbindService() {
            // Detach our existing connection.
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mCallbackText.setText("No Service...");
    }`

For service starting you must to call doBindService(), for closing - doUnbindService().